# Why cast the sender of an event to a control type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, casting

I am new to ASP.NET development and I am trying to comprehend why object casting is required when dealing with event handling.

I was reading *ASP.NET 4 Unleashed* and came across this code, but I do not understand the purpose of it at all. I don't get the point of the cast in the following method:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.Text = (Int32.Parse(btn.Text) + 1).ToString();
}
```

The HTML is here:

```
    First Counter:
<asp:Button
id=”Button1”
Text=”0”
OnClick=”Button_Click”
Runat=”server” />
<br /><br />
Second Counter:
<asp:Button
id=”Button2”
Text=”0”
OnClick=”Button_Click”
Runat=”server” />
```

I don't understand the point of casting `btn` to a `Button`. Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Its not button. its object is casted to button

Comment: btn is a instance of the Button class right?

Comment: all the types in .net inherit from object. yes.

Comment: Look at the argument type, its `object` not `button` so casting is compulsory for getting button specific properties and methods.

Comment: So I am casting the sender object to be of a button type?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a good beginner question: it's clear and shows reasoning skill. He doesn't understand why he needs to cast `sender` ("I don't understand the point of casting `btn`",he meant `sender`, that mistake there shows why he needs our help) . He read the code in a book, it's possible he didn't type the code into VS. If he had, we would have seen (via IntelliSense) that `sender` doesn't have any `Button` properties. He doesn't understand the history/nuances of why event handlers accept an `object` instead of the class of the control that sent the event i.e. `Button`.

Answer (score 3):

Until you have learned about the C# `event` keyword, and about `delegate` types, it will be difficult for you to fully comprehend the reasoning here. That said…

Note that the `sender` parameter in the method declaration has the type `object`. This is due to the standard pattern for events in .NET: the delegate type always uses an `object` parameter as the first parameter for the delegate's signature.

Doing it this way allows a small number of delegate types to be reused for a wide variety of events. Probably the most common delegate type used is `EventHandler`, which is you will find on a wide variety of events in any number of classes (hundreds in .NET, if not a thousand or more).

Rather than having the framework include delegate types for each possible sender, the method signature only uses `object`. Then it's up to the event handler (e.g. your `Button_Click()` method) to cast that `object` reference to the actual type expected.

Note that in many cases, the event handler does not need to use the `sender` parameter at all. Either it is attached only to a single event, on an object that can be referenced via an instance field in the class, or the sending object isn't needed at all for the handling of the event (fairly common for `Click` events…the only reason the `Button` object is needed here is that the event handler is a contrived example for the purpose of the reference you're reading).

Comment: Thank you for this information. Could you provide a link to some resources that would help me get upto speed in asp.net web forms development?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about ASP.NET per se. And I personally know very little about ASP.NET. But [here is a link](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+web+forms+development) that should be a good start.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for answering. This point especially, "Note that in many cases, the event handler does not need to use the `sender` parameter at all.". That's the question I wanted answered, why even cast `sender` when he could just have directly used `Button1`. The answer being: you don't have to use `sender` unless the handler is  used by more than one control.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an "Answer" per se as it's already been answered long ago.  But it is a question I struggled with as well in the beginning and I have not found a satisfactory answer for "Why" myself.  So I thought to just contribute my thoughts more as a "forum response".  I'm primarily a VB Programmer so forgive my intruding on a C# question, though I think most of this still applies.

Regarding Server Control Events and casting 'sender' or other "obvious" casts I tend to rely on implicit casting:

```
Private Sub gvSomeGridView_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvSomeGridView.RowDataBound
  If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    Dim this As GridView = sender
    Dim drv As DataRowView = e.Row.DataItem
    Dim dk as DataKey = this.DataKeys( e.Row.RowIndex )
    Dim lbl as WebControl = e.Row.FindControl("SomeLabel")  // <asp:Label ID="SomeLabel">

    // AttributeCollection is common to all WebControls
    lbl.Attributes("data-rowidx") = e.Row.RowIndex
    lbl.Attributes("data-whatever") = dk.Value

    // Now here an explicit Cast in required
    DirectCast(lbl, Label).Text = drv("SomeFieldName")
    ...
  End If
End Sub
```

I used to use `CType()` or `DirectCast()` etc. as appropriate but, at least within `Events`, it seemed to me to just extra words and affects readability.

After a while you come to understand that `sender` is always the control for which this Handler belongs (though not necessarily the control that triggered the event) I've found no benefit to explicit casting in these instances because the declared variable makes it quite clear and implicit casting does the rest.

But to the OP's question of "why", while it may be, arguably, better programming practice to cast, in the case of standard server control event handling, you really do not *need* an explicit cast when your trying to obtain what `sender` is holding.

Also Keep in mind that the code I write is not being executed thousands of times per second where you can make an argument for shaving off milliseconds per cast.

In any case, I hope this helps contribute to the explanation of "Why" or "Why Not"